# Edit a record without code

Tags: php, mysql, code-generation

I'm looking for some sort of (free) framework / script that generates code (or reads mysql metadata at runtime) to edit a mysql record that I can just insert into my existing website.

Something like: Give it credentials, tell it which table and how to get the ID (in this case `$_GET['id']`) and it spits out a HTML form and PHP code to select/update/insert it.

I'm sure something like this already exists but I can't find good google search terms.

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are off-topic here. Good google terms would be "crud generator" or "scaffolding".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good key word for searching would be: scaffolding

http://www.phpscaffold.com/

http://www.amplescaffolder.com/2009/12/18/ample-scaffolder-everything-youve-ever-wanted-in-a-php-scaffolding-package/

Comment: Then please mark this a the accepted answer :)

Comment: I had to wait for a few minutes before I could :p